# Is the boundary of a subset a subset of the supersets boundary

Tags: general-topology

Suppose there is a set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Define $(A,B)$ to be the separation of $X$ iff:

1. $A, B\subset X$
2. $A \cup B=X$
3. $A\cap B=\partial A\cap \partial B$

Define the "cut" of separation $(A,B)$ to be $C=A\cap B$.

Does this imply that $\partial C\subset\partial X$?

Intuitively it seems true, but I can't seem to prove it. I'm new to topological proofs, so I'm probably missing something quite obvious. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know any examples where this is true and $A,B$ are not disjoint?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that my understanding of what the boundary is, is wrong. I think I was conflating the boundary of 2 dimensional surfaces with the idea of a boundary of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Perhaps what I'm looking for is something else?

Answer (score 3):

No, here's a counterexample. Take $X$ to be the closed unit ball. Take $A$ and $B$ both to be a closed half of $X$. Then $C$ is a disc that divides $X$ in two halves, but this is not part of the boundary of $X$.

Comment: But that doesn't satisfy the definition of a separation presented in the question.

Answer (score 3):

No. For example, if $X=[0,1]^3$, $A=[0,\frac 12]\times [0,1]^2$, $B=[\frac 12, 1]\times[0,1]^2$, then $C=\partial C=\{\frac 12\}\times[0,1]^2\not\subseteq \partial X$.

Comment: Ok, so the boundary of the 2D square "cut" through this unit cube is the cut/square itself? I was confusing the 1-dimensional edges of the square cut with the boundary of the cut. 

Is it possible to find the boundary of this surface as a something 1-dimensional?

Comment: @Kcronix: Yes, if you consider it as a submanifold (with boundary) in its own right, rather than a subset of a topological space, but I think the definitions can become a bit tricky in this case.

Comment: This is a much better formalism for this intuition. Thanks a lot. I was just recalling the definition of a manifold boundary when you replied.

Comment: But that doesn't satisfy the definition of "separation" given in the question.

Comment: If you find the submanifold (C, O), where $C=A\cap B$ and take it's boundary, would that be a subset of the boundary of X. Assuming that A and B are submanifolds of X?

Comment: @Acccumulation: What does not satisfy it?

Comment: @Kcronix: It's a separate question. I think to properly answer the question, you need a more robust notion of a (sub)manifold with corners. I would also assume that $A$ and $B$ have the same dimension as $X$ (although I guess this should probably be implied by the hypothesis, assuming that $X$ itself is a manifold). As you say, this seems correct, but I'm not 100% sure offhand.